# PHP Tidy Module: unsupported node type?

Tags: php, tidy

When using the [PHP Tidy Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) (More Specifically, The tidy_repair_string function) I keep getting the following error: Unsupported node type:8. what does this error mean, and what can I do to get around this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Noone can help you without the html string you are providing to tidy.

Comment: The string is a 60k file, and contains data my company wouldn't be happy about me posting on a public website.

Comment: generalize it then perhaps? We shouldn't need to see it word for word. Just the general markup if that's acceptable, and check that the generalized version is still causing the error. -- It also might help if you break down your 60k file to see what exactly is making the function fail. Then you could post that snippet if you haven't been able to figure out why that bit is causing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I could figure out with my google-fu is I believe node type 8 is referring to comments. Seeing what you're feeding `tidy_repair_string()` that's making it fail would help.

Perhaps you could fiddle with tidy's comment config options, `fix_bad_comments` and `hide_comments`?

I could be completely off, but that was as much as I could uncover with what you've stated. Some more info would help greatly. Such as an example of code that's specifically producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also googled this issue without viewing anomareh's answer, and came to the same conclusion. tidy's nody type should use the same integers as the DOM node type inteegers.
8 stands for comment.

Watch out for parts of `<!--  -->`. I would look out for the source location of the error. If tidy doesn't give you a line number, reduce your string by manually splitting it. If a chunk is ok, investige the next chunck. This way you can locate the problem.
It is most probaby a malformed tag that looks like a comment to tidy. Maybe you have nested comments?